# Gerrit Code Review (on premis) does not start after fresh installation

Tags: gerrit

I installed a fresh instance of Gerrit Code Review v3.1.3 on Ubuntu 18.0.4.
For most of the options during installation I choose the defaults, except for the authentication which is LDAP in my case.

Gerrit should start directly after installation but unfortunatly it doesn't.

Checking the Gerrit-logs wasn't necessary becouse there were no logs generated for some reason...
So I checked the ports on the machine in case one of Gerrit's ports is in use, but it's not and I'm out of ideas where to continue my troubleshooting or even fix this issue.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: If you are starting fresh I would recommend using docker, this will be much easier to manage/upgrade etc

Comment: What command have you executed to start Gerrit? What was showed in the screen? Is there some error or warning message?

Comment: sorry for my later answer, it works properly now